# IIS url rewrite dont do anything

Tags: url, iis, url-rewriting

I would like to url redirect from:

`https://media.domain.com/link to file.ext`

to:

`https://media.domain.com:8080/link to file.ext`

I have made this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 

 <configuration> 

<system.webServer> 

    <security> 

      <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" /> 

    </security> 

    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" showFlags="Date, Time, Size, Extension, LongDate" /> 

    <rewrite> 

        <rules> 

            <rule name="Redirect to port 8080" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true"> 

                <match url="(.*)/(.*)/(.*)" ignoreCase="false" /> 

 

                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true"> 

                </conditions> 

 

                <action type="Redirect" url="http://{R:2}:8080/{R:3}" appendQueryString="false" /> 

 

            </rule> 

        </rules> 

    </rewrite> 

 </system.webServer> 

</configuration>
```

But when I enter `https://media.domain.com/link to file.ext` IIS just gives me a 404 error, and it does not redirect.

IIS simply ignores my url rewrite..

Any thoughts?

Comment: 1) Study Markdown syntax please. Badly formatted questions are hard to read. 2) Try to learn more on regular expressions (and tons of online testing tools you can use), and you can figure out that your regex pattern is wrong and it won't match the URL you entered. That's why your rule won't trigger.

Answer (score 0):

you could try below rule:

```
<rule name="domian rule" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^media.domain.com$" />
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://media.domain.com:8080/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
```